# Can an "unpackable" ZFS label be fixed?

Tags: zfs

Consider a data recovery case from a failed Thecus NAS RAID6. The RAID6 can be assembled in degraded mode to the point where a 10TB zfs_member filesystem is detected with a filesystem label of zfspool0. But zpool import fails...

```
# zpool import
  pool: zfspool0
    id: 11477212963182401177
 state: FAULTED
status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
    The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
    the '-f' flag.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
config:

    zfspool0    FAULTED  corrupted data
      lv0       FAULTED  corrupted data
```

Further zdb -l can unpack labels 0, 1, and 3. But label 2 fails to unpack (labels 1 and 3 omitted for brevity)...

```
 #  zdb -l /dev/vg0/lv0
--------------------------------------------
LABEL 0
--------------------------------------------
    version: 13
    name: 'zfspool0'
    state: 0
    txg: 9140386
    pool_guid: 11477212963182401177
    hostname: 'thecus'
    top_guid: 8696440750124555725
    guid: 8696440750124555725
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'disk'
        id: 0
        guid: 8696440750124555725
        path: '/dev/vg0/lv0'
        whole_disk: 0
        metaslab_array: 23
        metaslab_shift: 31
        ashift: 9
        asize: 11389711679488
        is_log: 0

--------------------------------------------
LABEL 2
--------------------------------------------
failed to unpack label 2
```

My thinking is if I can somehow get label 2 to unpack then zpool import may be possible. Any thoughts on how/if label 2 can be fixed? Perhaps it can be fixed by hand with a hex editor? If so it would help if anyone knows where the labels are located.

Comment: My understanding is that all 4 labels are the same so it should import even with only one of them, which suggests their may be more serious corruption than just the labels.

Comment: What gives me hope is that Photorec is able to carve out large intact files. So I hope the damage is minor.  But running Photorec on the 10TB volume will take months to finish.

Comment: So what happened when you tried what it suggested?

Comment: The exact same results are produced with:  zpool  import  -f